# Android set Tag, findViewWithTag

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-context

I'm trying to find an ImageView by tag. I assign a tag for the ImageView, but when I try to findViewWithTag, it returns null. I read that I should add to the view the childer with addChilder, but the view doesnt have this function. Can someone explaim to me how I can do this?

```
ImageView principal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen_home_0);
    principal.setTag("principal");
```

in other class(AsyncTask) that i pass the context

```
        View noMiembros = new View(context);

        ImageView er = (ImageView) noMiembros.findViewWithTag("principal");
        er.setImageBitmap(result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an Activity to AsyncTask and just use :

```
ImageView principal = (ImageView) passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.imagen_home_0);
```

or get inflater from Context like this :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_viw_that_contains_that_image, parent, false);

ImageView principal = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imagen_home_0);

//or by tag 
principal = (ImageView) row.findViewWithTag("principal");
```

Best wishes.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `findViewWithTag` on `noMiembros`
which is a new View.

You need to call `findViewWithTag` on a parent of the ImageView 
you are trying to reach.

But if you want to get your ImageView from within an AsyncTask, just call
`findViewById(R.id.imagen_home_0)`  on your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are ... mistaking those two tags.

`setTag()` can attach ANY object to the view, while the XML tag is only a string - I believe the `findViewByTag` will try to match the tag passed thru XML, not one attached through code - as it could be any object.

Why not just pass the `principal` imageView to the asyncthread?

Comment: This is incorrect. The method signature is public View findViewWithTag(Object tag).

Comment: The problem is noMiembros is a newly created view that does not contain the ImageView, and couldn't possibly contain it as it is not a VIewGroup